# Why are the Do While loops not stopping?

Tags: code-review, loop

Ive been staring at this for a while now and I am going cross-eyed.  I am writing a simply program to change colors of a 3 color LED.  It is working, but then I noticed the LED would sometimes flash.  I did a variety of tests and eventually, using the serial monitor, found out the issue.  The brightness should count down to a brightness level of 0 and up to a level of 255.  However, *sometimes* it counts below 0 to -1 and *sometimes* it continues infinitely past 255.  I cant figure out why.  Below is the code and the serial monitor outputs.  The only way I can stop is by manually setting the value outside the loop.  You can see those lines commented out to allow for the error.

```
int randLeg;  // var to pick a random leg

// set all 3 legs to max brightness at start
int legThreeBrightness = 255;
int legFiveBrightness = 255;
int legSixBrightness = 255;
int delayTime = 15;
int increment = 1;

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);     

    // set pins as output
    pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
    
    // turn all the LEDs on
    analogWrite(3, legThreeBrightness);
    analogWrite(5, legFiveBrightness);
    analogWrite(6, legSixBrightness);

    randomSeed(analogRead(0));  // seed rand num generator

}  

void loop() {  
  
    randLeg = random(4, 7);  // pick a random leg
    
    switch (randLeg) {
    case 4:  //-1 for pin 3
        if (legThreeBrightness == 255){
          do {
                Serial.println(legThreeBrightness);
                analogWrite(3, legThreeBrightness);
                delay(delayTime);
                legThreeBrightness = legThreeBrightness - increment;
             } while (legThreeBrightness >= 0);   
             //legThreeBrightness = 0;
        }
        else {
         do {
                Serial.println(legThreeBrightness);
                analogWrite(3, legThreeBrightness);
                delay(delayTime);
                legThreeBrightness = legThreeBrightness + increment;
             } while (legThreeBrightness <= 255);
             //legThreeBrightness = 255;
        }
      break;
      
    case 5:
        if (legFiveBrightness == 255){
          do {
                ////Serial.println(legFiveBrightness);
                analogWrite(5, legFiveBrightness);
                delay(delayTime);
                legFiveBrightness = legFiveBrightness - increment;
             } while (legFiveBrightness >= 0);  
             //legFiveBrightness = 0; 
        }
        else {
         do {
                ////Serial.println(legFiveBrightness);
                analogWrite(5, legFiveBrightness);
                delay(delayTime);
                legFiveBrightness = legFiveBrightness + increment;
             } while (legFiveBrightness <= 255);
             //legFiveBrightness = 255;
        }
      break;
    case 6:
        if (legSixBrightness == 255){
          do {
                ////Serial.println(legSixBrightness);
                analogWrite(6, legSixBrightness);
                delay(delayTime);
                legSixBrightness = legSixBrightness - increment;
             } while (legSixBrightness >= 0);   
             //legSixBrightness = 0;
        }
        else {
         do {
                ////Serial.println(legSixBrightness);
                analogWrite(6, legSixBrightness);
                delay(delayTime);
                legSixBrightness = legSixBrightness + increment;
             } while (legSixBrightness <= 255);
             //legSixBrightness = 255;
        }
      break;
   }
    
      
}
```

> 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 -1

and

> 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265

Comment: you can remove 2/3 of the code if you use arrays

Comment: @jsotola that is probably true, but doesnt change the error I am having,

Comment: first `do` loop counts to -1 ... the second `do` loop prints the -1 and counts to 256 ... second `do` loop keeps counting from 256  because `do-while` always runs at least once ... use `if (legThreeBrightness > 255){`

Comment: Seems to be the question title should changed slightly, such as "Why are the do while loops stopping later than I expect?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change `>=` and `<=` to `>` and `<` respectively.

You want it to stop at 0, but your do-while will do another round, since `0>=0` is true. So your code only stops at `-1` and `256`.

When `legThreeBrightness` is 256 it should be counting down, but your `if (legThreeBrightness == 255){` doesn't detect this, so the code will continue counting up. I'd probably change this line to `if (legThreeBrightness >= 255){` to prevent this from ever happening (which it shouldn't, but still).

Comment: Honestly, I think I actually tried this last night, but I will try it again.  It also doesnt explain why in only happens sometimes.  I will report back.

Comment: It's definitely this - you can see in the output it go out of bounds, and just keeps going. e.g. from one part of a run: `252
253
254
255
256
256
257
256
258
257
257
259
258
259
258
260
259
260
260
261
262
263
261
262
263
264
265
261
264
265
266
267
262
263`
 Another way to prevent the value going out of bounds is to not use a do while loop, which runs the loop BEFORE it tests the value. But you will still need to use `<` or `>` for the comparison as you don't want the value decremented/incremented past when you have reached the boundary of your range.

Comment: this fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues related to bounds checking. For the sake of brevity, since all there LED branches of the switch statement are the same, I will refer to `legNumBrightness` instead of the individual `legThreeBrightness`, `legFiveBrightness`, `legSixBrightness` variables since this applies to all three (individually).

Because `do while` loops always run once before testing the condition, you have an issue with the value of `legNumBrightness` going out of bounds. i.e. when it is equal to 255, it decrements by one, until it is zero, and then because `0>=0` is still true (0 *is* equal to 0, after all), it decrements once more, so `legNumBrightness` is now `-1`. So on the next visit of that `legNumBrightness = 255`, the increments up by one branch is taken, until it reaches `255 <= 255`, which is again true, and hence will go to 256. As the if bounds test used is only that of `legNumBrightness == 255`, it will only decrement if the value is  exactly 255. Thus if it is not 255, it will keep incrementing until the maximum value of an `int` is reached (32767), overflow to -32768, and probably keep toggling between -32768 and 32767.

So to fix this, you need to change the `if (legNumBrightness == 255)` bound checking to
`if (legNumBrightness >= 255)`. Now, because of the `do while` loop, `legNumBrightness` will still sometimes go to `-1` and `256`, but can no longer overrun past 256. To fix the `-1` and `256` overrun, remove the `=` from the do while tests so they become `while (legNumBrightness > 0)` and `while (legNumBrightness < 255)` and thus will not try to increment or decrement when the boundary has been reached.

I would also recommend using a `while()` loop in preference to a `do while()` loop, so the condition is checked *before* running the loop content, but it does not appear necessary from brief testing of this logic.

e.g. for legThreeBrightness

```
 case 4:  //-1 for pin 3
        if (legThreeBrightness >= 255){
          do {
                //Serial.println(legThreeBrightness);
                analogWrite(3, legThreeBrightness);
                delay(delayTime);
                legThreeBrightness = legThreeBrightness - increment;
             } while (legThreeBrightness > 0);   
             //legThreeBrightness = 0;
        }
        else {
         do {
                //Serial.println(legThreeBrightness);
                analogWrite(3, legThreeBrightness);
                delay(delayTime);
                legThreeBrightness = legThreeBrightness + increment;
             } while (legThreeBrightness < 255);
             //legThreeBrightness = 255;
        }
      break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Gerben that you need to change `>=` and `<=` to `>` and `<` respectively, for the `do-while` loop check.

Secondly, your `if` statement expects `legThreeBrightness` (et al) to be 255 in order to decrement the brightness. Because of your `while` statement is over-running 255 because of  `<= 255`, the `if` statement will always execute the `else` part and because it is a `do-while` it will execute the loop once, incrementing `legThreeBrightness`.

To fix this, change the `if` statement to check for a value above 250:

```C++
case 4:  //-1 for pin 3
    if (legThreeBrightness > 250){  // <---- Notice the > 250
      do {
            //Serial.println(legThreeBrightness);
            analogWrite(3, legThreeBrightness);
            delay(delayTime);
            legThreeBrightness = legThreeBrightness - increment;
         } while (legThreeBrightness > 0);   
         //legThreeBrightness = 0;
    }
    else {
     do {
            //Serial.println(legThreeBrightness);
            analogWrite(3, legThreeBrightness);
            delay(delayTime);
            legThreeBrightness = legThreeBrightness + increment;
         } while (legThreeBrightness < 255);
         //legThreeBrightness = 255;
    }
  break;
```

This is easy to check and you should see the problem disappear straight away.